# creating table from two different table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating table from two different table with query:

```
create table post_table as 
  ( select t1.id, t2.url, t2.desc, t2.preview, t2.img_url, 
           t2.title, t2.hash, t2.rate 
    from user_record  t1, post_data t2 
      primary key (t1.id, t2,hash))
```

what's syntax error here?

post_data

```
----
    url varchar(255)    No           
        desc    varchar(2048)   No           
        preview varchar(255)    No           
        img_url varchar(128)    No           
        title   varchar(128)    No           
        hash    varchar(128)    No       // This is one  
        rate    varchar(20) Yes     NULL
```

user_record

---

```
id  varchar(40) No           //This is 2nd
name    varchar(50) Yes     NULL         
email   varchar(50) Yes     NULL         
picture varchar(50) No
```

UPDATE:

```
create table post_table (
    id VARCHAR(40), url varchar(255),  preview varchar(255) , img_url varchar(128), title varchar(128), hash varchar(128), rate varchar(20)
        primary key (t1.id, t2,hash));

select t1.id, t2.url, t2.desc, t2.preview, t2.img_url, 
t2.title, t2.hash, t2.rate 
from user_record  t1, post_data t2;
```

Comment: What error message do you receive?

Comment: @AcyclicTau: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'primary key (t1.id, t2,hash ) )' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting the `CREATE TABLE` statement so we can see the `( )` pairing:

```
create table post_table as ( 
    select t1.id, t2.url, t2.desc, t2.preview, t2.img_url, t2.title, t2.hash, t2.rate 
    from user_record  t1, post_data t2 
    primary key (t1.id, t2,hash)
)
```

We can see that the primary key is being attached to the select statement.

Beyond that there are specific restrictions around general `CREATE TABLE` syntax can be used in a `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` statement.

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html

> The ENGINE option is part of the CREATE TABLE statement, and should
>   not be used following the SELECT; this would result in a syntax error.
>   The same is true for other CREATE TABLE options such as CHARSET.

You can how ever select keys by using syntax similar to:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->        PRIMARY KEY (a), KEY(b))
    ->        ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT b,c FROM test2;
```

So with your query re-work it to define the column types first, then the keys, then the select statement last. We don't know your data types but it would look something similar to:

```
create table post_table (
    id DATATYPE, url DATATYPE, desc DATATYPE...
    primary key (t1.id, t2,hash))
)
select t1.id, t2.url, t2.desc, t2.preview, t2.img_url, 
t2.title, t2.hash, t2.rate 
from user_record  t1, post_data t2
```

Comment: You seem to have a spurious ; between the create table and the select

Comment: Also please post each error as you receive it, that helps people to answer quicker :)

Answer (score 1):

You have put key definition BEFORE select.
Also you can't do key definition without fields, so if you need keys, you have put all table structure.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Other way is create index after creating table by use CREATE INDEX